# angularJS, a notification partial or modal that gets loaded for a few seconds and then disappears

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, modal-dialog, partial-views

Hi I am currently building an app using angularJS nodeJs. One of the features is to have individuals be able to send an email from the app. To do this they click a button which opens up a modal window. They fill out the form and then hit send. This causes the email to send and closes the window. Once the modal window closes and I get the response from node that the email was successfully sent I would like to have a simple way to display a bubble/modal or message to the user that simply says "Email was sent successfully". Ideally I would like to have this message appear for like 10 seconds and then disappear.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this in a simple manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paila/pc7jaz9f/)
Used angular toaster and simulated failure and success scenarios

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="emailCtrl">
  <div class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="errorEmailReq()">Send Email Failed       
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="btn btn-success" ng-click="successEmailReq()">Send Email Success
  </div>
</div>

<toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 10000}"></toaster-container>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['toaster']);

myApp.controller('emailCtrl', function ($scope, $http, toaster, $timeout) {
    $scope.errorEmailReq = function () {
        //Some API call for failure
        $http.get("/email_for_failure").error(function(){
         toaster.pop("error", "", "Email Delivery Failed");
        });
    };

    $scope.successEmailReq = function () {
        //Some API call for success
        $http.get("/").success(function () {
          toaster.pop("success", "", "Email sent successfully");
        });
    };
});
```

//Simulation for failing email sent request

```
myApp.factory("httpErrorInterceptor", ["$q", function ($q) {
    var myInterceptor = {
        "responseError": function () {
            return $q.reject("This is not a real failure call -- simulation");
        }
    };
    return myInterceptor;
}]);

myApp.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("httpErrorInterceptor");
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to add jQuery (or if you already have it included in your project) you could use [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).
There's even a toastr implementation made to work with angularJS, [here](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr).

Answer (score 0):

Open the modal as usual and within it's controller use `$timeout` to call `$modalInstance.dismiss();` after x seconds. I.E.

```
$timeout(function(){ $modalInstance.dismiss(); }, 10000);
```